# How to iterate through all cases when partitioning objects

Tags: algorithm, iteration

Suppose I have k identical items, I want to divide them into n groups. How do I iterate through every single possible combination?

So far I've wrote some numbers on a board. Suppose k = n = 4, then a systematically way to list them is to find all 4 digit numbers (where 0 can be a digit) that has their digits add up to k. In ascending order:

```
0 0 0 4
0 0 1 3
0 0 2 2
0 0 3 1
0 0 4 0
0 1 0 3
0 1 1 2
0 1 2 1
0 1 3 0
0 2 0 2
0 2 1 1
0 2 2 0
0 3 0 1
0 3 1 0
0 4 0 0
1 0 0 3
...
```

I wish to avoid first generating all combinations without regard to the sum then remove all the combinations that don't add up to k. Since this would generate k^n combinations and it might take a long time. It doesn't matter if it is a for or recursion, but it has to be reasonably efficient.

Comment: you can use a for loop(s) or recursion, for is a constant n and recursion you have to do recursive decent to figure out the time complexity

Comment: Pseudo code would be nice :)

Comment: well what have you tried so far? i am not here to do your work for you.

Comment: got stuck after writing two nested recursive function definitions. Wouldn't be asking questions if I know what to do...

Comment: can you please post your attempts as well, does it have to be recursive? can it be in a for? or are you looking for most efficient?

Comment: I'm almost positive this would be solvable as an equation on the Math forum.  Then the equation could be put into code, simple as that.

Comment: Calculating the different number of combinations is easy, it's just (n+k-1)C(k-1). But trying to construct every single one with loops or recursion is different...

Comment: @Suamere: I'm not so sure: expressing it as an equation is easy but the equation would have multiple variables and it may not be as easy to find all solutions that solve the equation.

Comment: The key phrase to search for is "integer partition"; you want to partition the integer `k` into `n` parts.  (These partitions can then be permuted.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find a solution through a combination of recursion and loop.

Here's the pseudo code (I have no idea how to write pseudo code...I'm denoting a list by [a; b; c ...]:

```
// Returns a list of integers in range [0, k].
function num_list k =
...


// Recursively generate all the possible partitions with [total] objects
// and [groups] partitions. Returns a list of list of integers.
function generate (int groups, int total) = {
    if (groups == 1) then {
        return [[total]];
    } else {
        int list nums = num_list total;
        // looping through all values for one of the partitions.
        int list list list container1;
        foreach (i in nums) {
            // recursive step - generate all combinations without the first 
            // partition
            int list list subset = generate (groups - 1) (total - i);
            // append the first partition onto each element of this list
            int list list container2 = [];
            foreach (l in subset) {
                container2.add(l.prepend i);
            }
            container1.add container2;
        }
        // Flatten just takes a list of lists, and extract everything in each
        // list and mesh everything together.
        return container1.flatten();
}
```

Here's the code in python:

```
# Recursively generate all the possible partitions with [total] objects
# and [groups] partitions. Returns a list of list of integers.
def generate (groups, total):
    if (groups == 1):
        return [[total]];
    else:
        nums = range(total + 1);
        # looping through all values for one of the partitions.
        container1 = [];
        for i in nums:
            # recursive step - generate all combinations without the first 
            # partition
            subset = generate (groups - 1, total - i);
            # append the first partition onto each element of this list
            container2 = [];
            for l in subset:
                container2 += [([i] + l)];
            container1 += [container2];
        # Flatten just takes a list of lists, and extract everything in each
        # list and mesh everything together.
        return [item for sublist in container1 for item in sublist];
```

And here's the code in...functional programming language ocaml:

```
(* Returns a list of integers in range [0, k]. *)
let num_list n : int list =
  let rec helper num =
    if num = 0 then
      [0]
    else
      num :: (helper (num - 1)) in
  List.rev (helper n)

(**
 * Recursively generate all the combinations when dividing total number of
 * objects among groups.
 *)
let rec generate groups total : int list list =
  (* generate all the possible *)
  match groups, total with
  | 1, t -> [[t]]
  | g, t -> 
    let nums = num_list t in
    (* looping through all values for the head group *)
    let helper e : int list list =
      let subset = generate (g - 1) (t - e) in
      (* appending in front of every single result from generate *)
      List.map (fun l -> e :: l) subset in
    List.flatten (List.map helper nums)
```